# HTML <div> aiignment error occurring in Django/Python

Tags: python, html, django

(included website image) Essentially, on my website it displays the "Browse Topics" as well as the list of Topics indented as though it is 3fr(It is navigation so it should be on the left) while the "2 Rooms Available" and their contents are displayed beneath but as 1fr. . X.X

***Home.html Code***

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<style>
    .home-container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    }
</style>


<div class="home-container">

    <div>
        <h3>Browse Topics</h3>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}">All</a>
        </div>


        {% for topic in topics %}
            <div>
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}?q={{topic.name}}">{{topic.name}}</a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div>
        <h5>{{room_count}} rooms available</h5>
        <a href="{% url 'create-room' %}">Create Room</a>

        <div>
           {% for room in rooms %}
           <div>
               <a href="{% url 'update-room' room.id %}">Edit</a>
               <a href="{% url 'delete-room' room.id %}">Delete</a>
               <span>@{{room.host.username}}</span>
               <h5>{{room.id}} -- <a href="{% url 'room' room.id %}">{{room.name}}</a></h5>
               <small>{{room.topic.name}}</small>
               <hr>
           </div>
   
           {% endfor %}
       </div>
   
   </div>



</div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

[Website Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owklU.png)
When I remove the browse topic column then the other column moves to the 3fr spot.
[SOmething commandeering the 1fr column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydOi3.png)

***Main.html File***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-9'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>StudyBud</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>

<body>

    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li></li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}
    
</body>
</html>
```

***Navbar.html File***

```
<a href="/">
    <h1>LOGO</h1>
</a>


<form method="GET" action="{% url 'home' %}">
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Rooms..." />
</form>

<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login<a/>

<hr>
```

Comment: There have been some meaningful updates to the code you've posted without updating the image. Are you sure this problem is still happening now?

Comment: Yes, the image hasn't changed regardless, as I update the code I have checked. I also just copy and pasted it to be sure and it is still affected by the problem.

Comment: My guess is it's due to caching an older version as SamSparx suggested. If you take that code for home.html and run it in a browser it looks as expected.

Comment: *Hits head on table* Restarted the server, loaded it in browser, same thing. :(
I just removed all the html from ***home.html***, loaded a blank page and then pasted it back in, reloaded, same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with - these divs seem to have gotten out of synch. They are closing off your home container too early. Try removing the last .

```
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

If you just put the raw html you have provided into a .html file and test, that seems to behave as you'd expect, with topic in 1fr and rooms in 3fr. If browse topics is still in your 3fr region, you may need to check your main.html template to see if something else is interfering.

Edit after additional files provided

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login<a/>
```

See the closing `<a/>` tag in your navbar file? That is mucking up everything.  Replace it with `</a>`

Comment: I removed the </div> and it didn't seem to affect anything. I posted the content of the Main.html + Navbar.html

Comment: @ChrisCarucci You removed the `</div>` on line 29 of the template file, right? Rather than the one on the second to last line of the file.

Comment: @HenryWoody Yes.

Comment: It seems a little weird that removing HTML structure didn't do anything. Can you check your HTML source in your browser to make sure your changes are going through - maybe try CTRL+F5 (cmd+shift+r on mac) to force a refresh on your webpage.

Comment: When I remove the "Browse Topics" column then everything, including the 'Rooms available' moves to the 3fr place.

Comment: I think I found the issue in your navbar file, and have appended a note to my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you, works 100%. I created a login function and after that the rror was occurring, never changed the navbar code so it never hit me. WHAT a STUPID oversight. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Happy to help. I don't think I've ever seen an unclosed A tag cause behaviour like that - so not exactly an intuitive fix.